# finding the half life of an Exponential decay problem.

Tags: calculus

More specifically, The rate of decay of a radioactive substance is proportional to the amount of substance present. What is the half-life of a radioactive substance if it takes 7 years for one-third of the substance to decay?

This is what i did:

I used the equation $A(t)=A_{0}e^{kt}$

I set

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3} &= e^{7k} \\
\implies k &= \frac{1}{7} \cdot \ln \left( \frac{1}{3} \right ) \\
\implies t &= \frac{\ln \left( \frac{1}{2} \right )}{\frac{1}{7} \cdot \ln \left( \frac{1}{3} \right )}
\end{align}

Comment: You are nearly right. But note that A is the amount of radioactive substance remains…not the amount that is gone. so you should have 2/3 = exp(7k)…in your answer, the half life is shorter than 7 years… which makes no sense

Comment: I would say: 7 years for one-third of the substance to decay then after 7 years will remain two-thirds of the substance.